# Можно ли использовать один datasource в нескольких приложениях?

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть приложение на spring, развернутое на WAS 8.5.5.13

Есть основное приложение, предоставляющее rest-API для работы с БД(создается transaction manager из datasource). Сам dataSource прописан на сервере и хранит в себе свойства для подключения к базе Oracle11g

На все том же сервере WAS для той же базы, планирую другое приложение, которое будет выгружать определенным образом данных из базы и выполнять над ними операции(как мне кажется это так же снизит нагрузку на основное приложение)

Оба приложения планируется эксплуатировать на одном и том же сервере, с одной и той же базой, используя один и тот же dataSource

Правильно ли это? Могут ли начать появляться проблемы из-за этого решения?

Comment: Ну если datasource не единичное соединение, а пул соединений то проблем не будет.

Comment: @zuzz наверное имееются ввиду pool connections к базе данных. Если оно со значением 50(как выставляет WAS по умолчанию), то соединений должно хватить.
А не могут ли возникнуть трудности с транзакциями?

Comment: Приложения не должны мешать друг другу. transaction manager открывает соединение с базой в момент запроса, а по завершении должен его закрыть иначе начнутся проблемы даже у одного приложения.